# Debugging the physical components in a circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, audio, circuit-design, debugging

What is the best approach to debug the physical components of a circuit that does not work?

I set up a circuit for a simple audio player following [this tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SimpleAudioPlayer).

However it simply does not work. The code portion of it seems to be functioning fine, but I'm unclear as to where to start debugging the physical components of the circuit. What would be the best approach to debug what is wrong in the circuit itself?

[image]

[image]

Comment: "*code portion of it seems to be functioning fine*" What does this mean when you also say the circuit simply does not work?

Comment: I have debugging in place i can monitor that logs the audio files as they are read from the sd card and played. So the code portion is fine. It's just not outputting the sound,so the issue is somewhere in the circuit.

Comment: Sounds (no pun intended) like the output isn't configured correctly.  Maybe start there.

Comment: You need to show a schematic of what your circuit is.

Comment: I added an image of the schematic.

Comment: First thing I'd do is check if the un-amplified audio signal is making it to the amplifier. Stick a scope on Vin, tell us what that shows.

Answer (score 1):

My build process is as follows. Some people will have different philosophies but this one has proven decent for standard electronic design for me (read: no high power, no RF). I complete steps 1, 2 and 3 for most circuits. I only move on to step 2 if the I pass step 1. I only move to step 3 if step 2 is good. Step 4 is only if I can not get anything to work and need to verify chip is not damaged. Most circuits will work after steps 1-3.

1. **Check Connections**

Use a multimeter in continuity mode to make sure power and GNDs are well connected. Check connection of Vin from circuit to cap. Ect. If something isn't connected that is supposed to be, connect it. If something is connected that isn't supposed to be, disconnect it. Simple and covers a lot of problems.

2. **Test DC Biasing**

Probe each node of the circuit. I expect to see 0V at each ground node, power at each VCC/VEE node, and in your case 0V at the input terminals of the amplifier. Check currents from power supply, from this circuit I wouldn't expect more than a milliamp of Iq (check datasheet to confirm Iq of amplifier, should be very low). If I saw strange voltage readings or high current consumption, I know something is wrong with the construction of circuit. This along with step 1 cover majority of mistakes.

3. **Test AC**

If DC stuff looks good, we can test AC. Applying test signals to check if an unloaded output reacts accordingly is the easiest way to do this. It seems like you have some highpass filtering on the input, and with cap gain of amplifier is 200 (according to your tutorial at least). So I would apply a signal of around 100Hz with a Vpp of 10mV. I got 10mV by dividing a supply of 3.3V / 200 and heavily rounding down so I know clipping shouldn't be an issue. I got 100Hz by looking at the iput filter's cutoff of 1.59Hz and moving away from it. With the pot turned fully I would expect to see an output of ~2Vpp or ~0Vpp depending on which way the pot is turned. Turning the pot should increase/decrease the output waveform.

If I don't see this, I check wiring, and then I check datasheet to make sure I'm using part correctly. Checking to make sure the input is present at the amplifier input (as @Hearth said) is another thing to check.

If anything is fishy here (distortion, no output, no input) investigate it. Follow the signal path the best you can. Prope Vin, top of pot, input of amp. You should see the input pass through the cap, and see a possibly attenuated input at amplifier.

4. **(If not working) Simplify Circuit**

If I do all of that and I still have nothing expected on the output I would simplify the circuit. In this case the circuit is already pretty simple so I can't do that much, if there are more complicated circuits I would remove them and verify all parts and ICs are in working order. This is to check if a part is burnt out or otherwise not working. You can also remove all components and measure their values to ensure that they are correct. This is more of a last resort.

Comment: Can you please exp-and upon this... "Use a multimeter in continuity mode to make sure power and GNDs are well connected. Check connection of Vin from circuit to cap"
I'm not quite sure how to use continuity mode. My understanding was that I just put the multimeter into continuity mode, and then put the multimeter in between the capacitor and Vin.

Comment: I don't believe that will work as continuity mode attempts to force a constant DC current, which the cap will block. You want to check that all the wires/traces connecting power/ground have low impedance. I recommend looking up a tutorial for a handheld multimeter

Comment: You should be able to put multimeter in capacitive measure mode and get a rough measurement of input cap. This is just to ensure the ballpark cap value is right.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Is measuring the capacitance in capacitive measure mode part of the Step 1 you mentioned for "Check connections" or is this a completely different step?

Comment: Oops, my apologies, I misinterpreted what you were asking. What I meant is to check the connection from the arduino to the input of your circuit (using continuity mode). Just to make sure your wiring is ok.

Comment: Are you referring to putting the multimeter in between the arduino 5v pin and the input of the circuit?

Comment: No, I'm referring to verifying the connection of the arduino output to your circuit input. The long blue wire on your picture. Not that I think that's a problem, just that if it isn't connected it would be an issue.